# Dynamically change DataLabels color based on line color of graph

Tags: excel, vba

My code below does not work in changing the color of the added Label of the line graph based on its corresponding color line. I'm getting the error **Type Mismatched**.

Z variable is the number/count of lines currently on the graph. Will be changing this as well to dynamic soon and might be more than 6 which is the limit of msoThemeColorAccent.

```
ThemeLineTextColor = "msoThemeColorAccent" & FullSeriesCollectionList
.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = ThemeLineTextColor
```

Here's my full code:

```
Z = 3

FullSeriesCollectionList = 1
Do Until FullSeriesCollectionList > Z
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 39").Activate
        ThemeLineTextColor = "msoThemeColorAccent" & FullSeriesCollectionList

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 39").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).Points(x).Select
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelRight)
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).Points(x).DataLabel.Select
    Selection.ShowSeriesName = -1

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 39").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(FullSeriesCollectionList).Points(x).DataLabel.Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = ThemeLineTextColor
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    FullSeriesCollectionList = FullSeriesCollectionList + 1
Loop
```

Edit1: Formating

Comment: `ThemeLineTextColor = "msoThemeColorAccent" & FullSeriesCollectionList` you can't get the actual *value* of a constant by concatenating a string that *looks like* the constant.  Maybe instead make an array of RGB values and use that array in your loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams but if i use RGB then it I have to manually adjust the RGB code. What I need is to dynamically change the color based on its corresponding line color.

Comment: Can you update with the full Sub?  What is `x` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will format the datalabel on the fifth point in the first 3 series:

```vb
Sub ChartPointFormatting()
    Dim cht As Chart, seriesNum As Long, s As Series, p As Point
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 39").Chart
    cht.SetElement msoElementDataLabelNone
    
    For seriesNum = 1 To 3
        Set s = cht.FullSeriesCollection(seriesNum)
        Set p = s.Points(5) 'for example
        p.HasDataLabel = True
        With p.DataLabel
            .Position = xlLabelPositionRight
            .ShowSeriesName = True
            With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
            End With
        End With
    Next seriesNum
    
End Sub
```

Note there's typically no need for Select/Activate when working with objects in Excel.  That's an artifact of how the macro recorder writes code - it just follows your exact steps.

Comment: If this answered your question, please flag as "Accepted" so that anyone else coming along later with a similar problem can see there's a working answer.

Comment: Yes this was awesome! It worked perfectly! I've learned alot from this code!