# Programatically adjust Line Labels to not overlap in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to adjust the overlapping labels of my line graph **but only on the showing labels** and it should be sorted from highest to lowest.

I have an exisitng macro code that would show and change the color of the label. The help I need is to adjust multiple label so it will be readable and sorted according to its ranking.

I'm using this Macro Code for showing label: [Dynamically change DataLabels color based on line color of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590065/dynamically-change-datalabels-color-based-on-line-color-of-graph)

Overlapping Label for editing:
[image]

Not overlapping and placement of labels are sorted from Highest to Lowest (Needed Result):
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried using this but its not working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770429/excel-macro-to-fix-overlapping-data-labels-in-line-chart

Comment: None of those answers had code you could use?  It does look a little complex, but so is the requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for you - it just spaces out the labels equally:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChartPointFormatting()
    Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, p As Point, l As Variant
    Dim labels As New Collection, tmax, delta, pos
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    cht.SetElement msoElementDataLabelNone
    
    For Each s In cht.FullSeriesCollection
        Set p = s.Points(s.Points.Count) 'for example
        
        s.HasLeaderLines = True 'make sure labels are connected to points
        s.LeaderLines.Format.line.ForeColor.RGB = s.Format.line.ForeColor.RGB
        p.HasDataLabel = True
        With p.DataLabel
            .Position = xlLabelPositionRight
            .ShowSeriesName = True
            
            With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .ForeColor.RGB = s.Format.line.ForeColor.RGB
            End With
        End With
        labels.Add Array(p.DataLabel, p.DataLabel.Top) 'add label and position to collection
    Next s
    
    SortCollection labels, 2  'sort collection by label tops
    pos = labels(1)(1)               'min top
    tmax = labels(labels.Count)(1)   'max top
    delta = (tmax - pos) / labels.Count
    
    For Each l In labels
        l(0).Top = pos
        l(0).Left = l(0).Left + 20 'nudge right a bit
        pos = pos + delta
    Next l
End Sub


'Sort a collection of 0-based arrays in ascending order by the n'th element of each array
'Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588073/478884
Sub SortCollection(col As Collection, n As Long, Optional AscendingSort As Boolean = True)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, vTemp As Variant, v1, v2
    For i = 1 To col.Count - 1 'Two loops to bubble sort
        For j = i + 1 To col.Count
            v1 = col(i)(n - 1)
            v2 = col(j)(n - 1)
            If IIf(AscendingSort, v1 > v2, v1 < v2) Then
                vTemp = col(j)
                col.remove j
                col.Add Item:=vTemp, Before:=i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]